# Marshalling C struct containing arrays to C#

Tags: c#, pinvoke

With great help of the **stackoverflow** community, I've managed to call a native DLL function. However, I can't **modify** the values of `ID` or `intersects` array. No matter what I do with it on the DLL side, the old value remains. It seems read-only.

Here are some code fragments:

C++ struct:

```
typedef struct _Face {
    int ID;
    int intersects[625];
} Face;
```

C# mapping:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct Face {
        public int ID;

        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 625)]
        public int[] intersects;
    }
```

C++ method (type set to DLL in VS2010):

```
extern "C" int __declspec(dllexport) __stdcall 
solve(Face *faces, int n){
for(int i =0; i<n; i++){
    for(int r=0; r<625; r++){
        faces[i].intersects[r] = 333;
        faces[i].ID = 666;
        }
    }
```

C# method signature:

```
[DllImport("lib.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
public static extern int solve(Face[] faces, int len);
```

C# method invocation:

```
Face[] faces = new Face[10];
faces[0].intersects = new int[625];
faces[0].ID = -1; //.. and add 9 more ..

solve(faces, faces.Length);

// faces[0].ID still equals -1 and not 666
```

Kindest regards,
e.

Comment: I had a similar question about a year ago. I ended up marshalling a pointer to an array. Take a look as it might help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4464532/im-trying-to-marshal-a-struct-from-c-to-c-not-sure-where-to-start

Comment: I could swear this was asked just a day or 2 ago (not by @Queequeg though).

Comment: By the way, in your previous question I told you that you should not use `SetLastError` on your functions. That is for Windows API functions only. That same advice still applies. The CharSet and CallingConvention settings are option in C# since you are using the C# defaults. I'd remove them too since they just add clutter.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to tell the pinvoke marshaller explicitly that the array needs to be marshaled back.  You do this with the [In] and [Out] attributes.  Like this:

```
    [DllImport("...")]
    public static extern int solve([In, Out] Face[] faces, int len);
```

Comment: this does not change the behavior.. :(

Comment: I tested this before I posted, using the exact declarations and a DLL written in C++ compiled with VS2008.  I'm quite sure it works.

Comment: It works. I also have run this code. I was 99% of the way there with my answer, but Hans beat me to it (again!) Please try again.

Answer (score 0):

This is an output field only? To get to the bottom of this, I'd try substituting your Face[] parameter with a large-enough a byte[] and see if the byte array gets filled with anything (you'll have to change your [DllExport] a bit).

Also, one other thing I used to experience when doing this with char*'s is that I had to pre-allocate the buffer in C#. For example:

```
StringBuilder theString=new StringBuilder();
MyUnmanagedFunction(theString);
```

would not work. But assuming that returned theString was a max 256 characters, I would do this:

```
StringBuilder theString=new StringBuilder(256);
MyUnmanagedFunction(theString);
```

And I'd be in business. I'd recommend trying the byte[] substitution, if that doesn't work, try the pre-allocated byte array. Once you are seeing the byte array actually get changed by your C++ code, then you can figure out how to marshal that thing into your C# struct.